# Placing a space before and after a char that is not in a-to-z and 0-9

Tags: php

This is for analyzing a string... in need to explode a string to get all chars. Basically:

```
$string = "This is (1990-2002) some, text [after] this.";
```

What do i need to do to get this:

```
$string = "This is ( 1990 - 2002 ) some , text [ after ] this .";
```

This can be something like:

```
$string = str_replace('','',$string);
```

Note: It is not a problem if double spaces get inserted ill remove it...

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$string = "This is (1990-2002) some, text [after] this.";
$pattern = '/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/';
$replace_pattern = ' $1 ';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace_pattern, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $string = 'This is (1990-2002) some, text [after] this.';

 $replace = preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9\s])/", " $1 ", $string);
 // This is ( 1990 - 2002 ) some , text [ after ] this .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = '';
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
    if(ctype_alnum($string[$i])) {
        $out .= $string[$i];
    } else {
        $out .= ' ' . $string[$i] . ' ';
    }
}
// $out contains the fixed string
```

Comment: That would cause double spacing in the case of `text [text] text`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha > Note: It is not a problem if double spaces get inserted ill remove it...